# How can I create a log file in java using loggers (log4j or slf4j) in the place where we run the application(jar) or source code?

Tags: java, logging, jar, log4j

I am bundling my source code as jar or a standalone application which would be running in the Linux environment.So,whenever I run the application the log files must be generated in the drive where the application runs.
The output log file path is not static.
I tried using the log4j properties..but it doesn't worked as the path varies dynamically.

Comment: You can also setup log4j programmatically: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html . Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the current directory

Comment: @Prabhu why don't you try like log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out. I guess log.out should be generated where application is run. Have a look at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html. it will also help saving logs on date basis

Answer (score 0):

You can use *System Properties* as variables in your log configuration (as decribed in [Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html))

Consider this example:

**log4j2.xml** - look for `${sys:loghome}`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="A1" fileName="${sys:loghome}/A1.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="stack" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**LogMe.java**

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

```
public class LogMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // For testing System.setProperty("loghome", "C:/Daten/");
        Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("stack");
        log.info("Logged");
    }
}
```

This will store the logfile relative to System property "loghome".

**Final Step**

Set System Property at start:

```
java -Dloghome=. LogMe
```

By passing in the correct directory where logs should be put, you can control the logfile creation.

**log4j2.properties** just a quick example

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = ${sys:loghome}/FromProperty.log 

appenders = console, rolling

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:loghome}/log-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100MB
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

loggers = rolling

logger.rolling.name = stack
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: Please,can I expect the same in a properties file configuration.

Comment: For Log4j2 ? or log4j 1.3 or which do you prefer?